# Find all the factors of a number from the prime factors

Tags: math, factors

Using Elliptic curve factorization (in Python) I am able to find the PRIME factors of a 50 digit number in ~0.5 sec. Is there any way I can convert the prime factors to the factors of the number?

What I have realized by testing on small digits (496 and 28), multiplying the prime factors together in a specific order. Then multiplying those numbers almost gives me the factors, but it is not very flexible because I have only gotten the formula of what I need to multiply together from small list of prime factors (1,2,3,5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my version, which computes the element-wise products of the powerset of the set of prime factors, keeping only those products that are unique:

```
def divisors(n, fs=[]):
    if fs == []: fs = factors(n)
    divs = [1]
    for f in fs:
        temp = divs[:]
        for d in divs:
            if f * d not in temp:
                temp.append(f*d)
        divs = temp
    return sorted(divs)
```

And here it is in action:

```
>>> factors(496)
[2, 2, 2, 2, 31]
>>> divisors(496)
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248, 496]
>>> factors(28)
[2, 2, 7]
>>> divisors(28)
[1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28]
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late reply, I had school. Could you explain what each step does. I am slightly confused about what divs and fs represents. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: The accumulating list of divisors is in `divs`, and `fs` is the factors of _n_. You didn't ask, but `temp` is a copy of `divs`, so that `divs` can be used in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is factored into powers of primes, like p^a q^b r^c then the possible factors of the number are all numbers of the form p^x q^y r^z for 0 ≤ x ≤ a, 0 ≤ y ≤ b, and 0 ≤ r ≤ z.

Since you can have different numbers of prime factors, this is a little programming problem. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the product of each (unique) set in the powerset. So for `18=2*3*3` you want the product for each set in `{{},{2},{3},{3},{2,3},{2,3},{3,3},{2,3,3}}`, giving you `{1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 9, 18}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sympy module like this:

```
import sympy
sympy.ntheory.factorint(4960) #Factorization.
sympy.ntheory.divisors(4960) #List all divisors.
```